# Updating a nested mongodb object fails

Tags: mongodb

I have this mongodb data i have stored in this way

```
db.orders.insert( { _id: ObjectId().str, name: "admin", status: "online",catalog : [
        {
            "objectid" : ObjectId().str,
            "message" : "sold",
            "status" : "open"
        }
    ]})
```

and i am trying to update it in this manner `db.orders.update({"_id":"5703b86df3d607cb5fa75ff3"},{$set: {"catalog.message": "added to cart"}})`

and this is the error message i am getting

```
> db.orders.update({"_id":"5703b86df3d607cb5fa75ff3"},{$set: {"catalog.message": "added to cart"}})
WriteResult({
    "nMatched" : 0,
    "nUpserted" : 0,
    "nModified" : 0,
    "writeError" : {
        "code" : 16837,
        "errmsg" : "cannot use the part (catalog of catalog.message) to traverse the element ({catalog: [ { objectid: \"5703b86df3d607cb5fa75ff4\", message: \"sold\", status: \"open\" } ]})"
    }
})
```

How can i update this record?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [MongoDB's Examples](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#examples) you should provide the index of the Object in the array which you want to update. Since you want to update the first object i.e. object in the array at index 0 use this :

```
db.orders.update(
    {"_id":"5703b86df3d607cb5fa75ff3"},
    {$set: {"catalog.0.message": "added to cart"}});
```

Comment: Your answer gives this `WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 0, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 0 })
`

Comment: Please check again. Updated the answer.